# Pinia Composed Store + Vue3 reactivity problem

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, pinia

Stack Blitz Illustration of Problem: [StackBlitz](https://vue-n4bkuz.stackblitz.io)

I am composing a pinia store in which one of the actions calls the server to save data from the stores state. This action is called by a watcher on the state in question. The server returns the updated data after save and I want to set this data to my state.

Right away I noticed that this introduces an infinite loop in my code:
set state (triggers) save state on server (triggers) set state. My idea to fix this is to use another reactive value to disable the watcher at the right moment.

Here is the store ( There is also a stack blitz link at the top of this question )

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

// for mocking an api request
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
  const numberValue = ref(null);
  const disabledAutoSave = ref(false);

  // save function on the server returns the newly updated data
  const saveData = async () => {
    console.log('saving!');
    await timeout(250); // mock response time from server
    let newData = { numberValue: 5 }; // static value here for mockup
    disabledAutoSave.value = true;
    numberValue.value = newData.numberValue;
    disabledAutoSave.value = false;
  };

  // get data from server
  const getData = async () => {
    console.log('getting!');
    await timeout(250); // mock response time from server
    disabledAutoSave.value = true;
    numberValue.value = 1; // static mock - in practice this is the server data
    disabledAutoSave.value = false;
  };

  let debounce = ref(null);
  watch(numberValue, () => {
    if (!disabledAutoSave.value) {
      if (debounce.value) clearTimeout(debounce.value);
      debounce.value = setTimeout(async () => await saveData(), 250);
    }
  });
  return {
    numberValue
  };
});
```

The problem is that the `saveData()` method is getting called when the `saveData()` method is setting `numberValue`. I thought that this could be due to Vue and how it can batch updates so I tried to implement nextTick to fix the problem but it did not fix it.

Please help!! Thank you
Stack Blitz Illustration of Problem: [StackBlitz](https://vue-n4bkuz.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I was able to work around this by providing an action for setting the state, and then triggering the server save from the action, rather than using a watcher of the state. This is fine but I'd like to implement the idea I have above if it is possible.

Comment: The problem is that setTimeout is unaware of promises, it's semantically incorrect to use `async` callback there. You can just use promise-aware debounce instead of reinventing it with setTimeout